# Trying to get data from server - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, react-fullstack

I'm trying to set the default value of the select element to be the information im getting back from the server but it keeps throwing the error, even though I know that user.roleId is not undefined, in the other inputs its working perfectly and only in the select element its throwing this error.

The code :

```js
function UsersForm() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<any>({});
  const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let id = location.pathname.split('/')[4];
      let res = await loadUser(id);
      let foundUser = await res.json();
      setUser(await foundUser);
    })();
  }, []);

  const loadUser = async (id: string) => {
    return await fetch(baseUrl + id, {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form autoComplete="off" autoCorrect="off" autoSave="off" onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="form-row justify-content-center mb-3">
            <div className={'form-group col-md-3'}>
              <label>Username</label>
              <input type="text" className="form-control" id="userName" defaultValue={user.userName} disabled />
            </div>
            <div className={'form-group col-md-3'}>
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" defaultValue={user.email} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-row justify-content-center mb-3">
            <div className={'form-group col-md-3'}>
              <label>Role</label>
              <select name="role" id="role" defaultValue={Roles[Number.parseInt(user.roleId)].toString()}>
                {Object.keys(Roles).map((role: string) => {
                  if (!isNaN(Number.parseInt(role))) {
                    return <option key={Number.parseInt(role)}>{Roles[Number.parseInt(role)].toString()}</option>;
                  }
                })}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className={'form-group col-md-3'}>
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="email" className="form-control" id="email" defaultValue={user.email} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-5">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-orange btn-block mt-4 sign-up-button">
                Update
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="form-row justify-content-center p-0">
          <div className="col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-5">
            <BackButton path="users" className="btn btn-orange btn-block sign-up-button mb-5" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The Roles enum :

```js
export enum Roles {
  Admin = 1,
  User = 2,
  Other = 3,
}
```

I think what is happening is that once the component is loading the user.roleId is still undefined but after couple of milliseconds its getting the information from setUser function...
how can I solve this problem?

link to the project : https://github.com/DanielOphir/ReactUI

Comment: Does the `<select />` element have a `defaultValue` prop? I'm pretty sure [it doesn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select); did you mean to use [react-select](https://react-select.com/)?

Comment: in react it has defaultValue, the problem is that the user is undefined when the component is loading and after milliseconds its getting defined

Answer (score 0):

Well, one approach would be to assign a `null` value to `defaultValue` while the data is been fetch.

```
<select 
  name="role" 
  id="role" 
  defaultValue={user.roleId ? Roles[Number.parseInt(user.roleId)].toString() : null}
>
  {Object.keys(Roles).map((role: string) => {
     if (!isNaN(Number.parseInt(role))) {
       return <option key={Number.parseInt(role)}> 
       {Roles[Number.parseInt(role)].toString()}</option>;
     }
   })}
</select>
```

Comment: but then its always null, it doesnt get any notification when the user.roleId is set so its not changing it...

Comment: Did you try it? Once the object has the data it should render..

Comment: yes I tried... it doesnt re-render for some reason...

Comment: Can I have access to the code somewhere?

Comment: later this day i will upload it and send it to you :)

Comment: Can you show what's the API json response?

Comment: I recommend axios for API is much better than fetch..

Comment: I added link to the repo in the question.
the API json response is :
{
city: "x"
email: "admin@admin.com"
houseNumber: "x"
id: "47f44e73-2c08-4fc2-6f8b-08d9bf0734b3"
firstName: "Daniel"
lastName: "Ophir"
phoneNumber: "x
roleId: 1
street: "x"
userName: "admin"}

Comment: I have no idea what's going on. You could try `defaultValue={user.roleId ? "test" : null}` just to see if the problem lies on `Roles[Number.parseInt(user.roleId)].toString()`  .. The JSX ternary operator should work... Their might be a problem which is making your variable undefined when the API is fetched.